# Copy node from TreePanel to TreePanel keeping the structure

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, extjs6

I have problem with script that will allow me to copy nodes from one Tree to another keeping the structure of folders.

Here's the script written in extjs 6.0
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dr0

I am able to reconstruct structure from the source tree but unfortunately the copied element is duplicated and I don't know how to handle this. I am not sure if the way how I am doing this is correct so any tips will be helpfull.

The main logic is here:

```
beforedrop: function (node, data, overModel, dropPosition, dropFunction, eOpts) {
    eOpts.trackedParentsNodeList = [];
    createParentList(data.records[0], eOpts.trackedParentsNodeList);

    var currentNode = node;
    for (var i = eOpts.trackedParentsNodeList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var newNode = createCloneNode(eOpts.trackedParentsNodeList[i]);
        currentNode.appendChild(newNode);
        currentNode = currentNode.lastChild;
    }
}
```

and here

```
createParentList = function(data, result){
    result.push(data);
    if(data.parentNode && data.parentNode.id !== "root")
        createParentList(data.parentNode, result);
    else return false;
}

createCloneNode = function(node){
    return {
        "text": node.data.text,
        "leaf": node.isLeaf(),
        "expanded": node.isExpanded()
    };
}
```

---

**ok, so I was managed to solve this problem and here's solution** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dr0.

Not sure if that's best way to do this, but it works.